# Ensure uniqueness of a nested value in JSONB in Rails ActiveRecord without self.class.exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Normally, we could use `self.class.exists?(api_key: api_key)` to check if any other row in the table has a value before we save:

```rb
def set_api_key
  self.api_key ||= loop do
    api_key = SecureRandom.hex(24)
    break api_key unless self.class.exists?(api_key: api_key)
  end
end
```

But in this example, `api_key` is actually a value on a JSONB column called `config`:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :set_api_key, on: [:create]
  validates :api_key, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  store_accessor :config, :status, :plan, :api_key

  def set_api_key
    self.api_key ||= loop do
      api_key = SecureRandom.hex(24)
      break api_key unless self.class.exists?(api_key: api_key)
    end
  end
end
```

Assume `:status`, `:plan`, `:api_key` are all top-level attributes of a JSONB column called `config`.

This results in: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.api_key does not exist`

Is there a slick Rails-way of achieving this in a similar way that `self.class.exists?(key: value)` works? Is there a low-cost SQL query to use instead?

Comment: What Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma v9.6.3 locally. is there a v11/12 feature that could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's special operators for use with json(b) ([Postgres Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html))

The `->>` will access a jsonb element as a string, ie. `config->>api_key` instead of `config.api_key`

You should be able to do this `self.class.exists?('config->>api_key = ?', api_key)`